# Calculating Uncertainty for categorical predictions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, categorical-data, confusion-matrix

I am wondering what is the best way to calculate the uncertainty for my categorical predictions. I have created a model that predicts what rating a movie is getting based on certain keywords and the amount of times these key words are mentioned. I have trained the model with a small data matrix and now I am running it though a bigger data matrix that has data from over 20,000 reviews. I have used different models and different variations of my dataset (feature engineering and feature selection) and now that I have my results from my best model/dataset combination, I want to learn how to calculate the uncertainty of my results per rating. Could I use the confusion matrix or other metrics (sensitivity etc) to calculate the uncertainty?

Example Predictions:
Rating1:   1000
Rating2:   25
Rating3:   59
Rating4:   599
Rating5:   3569

Thank you!

Comment: What do yo mean by "uncertainty" ? Is it the average error of your predictor ? Or the variance of your predictor error (see bias-variance tradeof) ? Or the self-estimated confidence that your model has about its predictions ?

Comment: I am looking more towards the self-estimated confidence that the model has for the predictions, thanks for the follow-up